# Mostrar/Esconder div utilizando um 'radio button'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom estou precisando verificar o estado do meu `radio button` para fazer com que caso ele esteja ativo no **"Sim"**, ele abra a `<div class="camposExtras">`, se clicar em **"Não"** ele fecha a `div`, e isto deverá ficar acessível a todo o momento.

Meus `radio button` abaixo:

```
<input type="radio" class="FlgPontua" name="FlgPontua" value="Sim" checked>
<input type="radio" class="FlgPontua" name="FlgPontua" value="Nao">
```

E a minha `div` é:

```
<div class="camposExtras">
    Aqui vem os dados que é para esconder ou aparecer
</div>
```

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
$(".FlgPontua").change(function() {
   console.log('entro aqui')
   if ($(this).val() == "Sim") {
      $('.camposExtras').show();
   }else{
      $('.camposExtras).hide();
   }
});
```

Porém não está me retornando nada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não estavas lá muito longe de conseguir fazer o código funcionar.
Em vez de apontares para a class `.FlgPontua`, tens que apontar para o `name="FlgPontua"`.

```js
$('input[name="FlgPontua"]').change(function () {
    if ($('input[name="FlgPontua"]:checked').val() === "Sim") {
        $('.camposExtras').show();
    } else {
        $('.camposExtras').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="FlgPontua" value="Sim" checked>
<input type="radio" name="FlgPontua" value="Nao">

<div class="camposExtras">
    Aqui vem os dados que é para esconder ou aparecer
</div>
```

Comment: Por algum motivo aqui não está funcionando

Comment: Ele aqui no StackOverflow está a funcionar corretamente. Exprimentou clicar ali no botão `Executar` código para ver ele em ação?

Comment: Sim, esqueci de um detalhe importante utilizo um css diferente o botão iCheck

Comment: o site é este http://icheck.fronteed.com/

Comment: consegui, obrigado pelo apoio